# How can I switch between 2 different webcams during a Webex presentation?

Tags: webcam, conferencing

Am looking to give sales presentations that will sometimes show the speaker via one webcam,and   a close up of a small product on another. I'm thinking of using Webex for this under Windows,  7 but am open to other suggestions...

Comment: I have seen virtual webcan drivers that allows you to multiplex webcam feeds or add special features. Maybe it will also allow you to switch between webcams.